# How to reveal Word TOC style that I renamed and deleted but appears to still be there?

Tags: troubleshooting, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I renamed **TOC 2** to **TOC 2,Topic** then inadvertently deleted it.

Now I cannot get the TOC 2,Topic style back, nor can I the factory TOC 2 style; i.e.:

- I cannot find TOC 2 in any variation in the Manage Styles list.
- I cannot recreate it. Word reports "It already exists or is reserved for a built-in style.
- I cannot copy the style from another document into this one. Word reports "The style refers to more than one style in the destination document."

I know I can fake a recovery by, for example, creating another TOC 2 variation such as TOC 2,Topics (plural). Or by copying everything into a new document. But this has happened before, so I'd really like to know how to recover from the problem, to prevent the problem, or both.

**Note**: This question may be related to another that I just posted:
https://superuser.com/questions/1041748/how-to-prevent-custom-toc-styles-from-automatically-updating

Comment: Have you tried the obvious - closing word and reopening the document?

Comment: Yes, several times. I also considered rebuilding normal.dot, but the time stamp indicates that it has not been changed. Oddly, Building Blocks.dotx **did** have an updated time stamp. Though there was no reason for it, I looked at it just in case and could not find anything related to TOCs.

Answer (score 0):

From the Manage Styles dialogue box, sort the styles alphabetically and un-tick 'Show recommended styles only', because Word must have re-created TOC2 but not as a visible style (or recommended one)

If TOC2 is not in the list yet, insert a table of contents (REFERENCES -> Table of Contents) and check the list in Manage Styles. This probably will re-generate TOC missing styles.

Comment: Yes, that regenerates the TOC 2. However, I cannot rename it to TOC 2, Topic. Word gives the error "The style name already exists or is reserved for a built-in style." 

So my custom rename is still lurking somewhere in Word's dark underbelly.

Comment: Well, why particularly you want such a name? You can never name a style that begins with reserved strings for built-in styles. Try to name a new style as `Heading 5,smith`; you can't do it even if you hadn't rename `Heading 5` to that name, but using `Heading 5smith` is OK.

Comment: Why do I want such a name? Per my original post: For headings, to make evident the structural names of the document (part, chapter, etc.); and for TOC levels, to make evident the mapping between headings and TOC levels. // No disagreement about naming strings with built-in, reserved names. Your examples, however, are faulty. Heading 5smith or Heading 5 smith results in Heading 5,Heading 5 smith ("Heading 5" repeated twice in the style name). Heading 5,smith results in Heading 5,smith. // In any case, "heading" is not the issue. "TOC" is.

Comment: (1) My example is valid and clear; you cannot name a NEW STYLE as `Heading 5,smith` (not rename a default one as you misunderstood me). It was meant to demonstrate that default style names like `TOC`, `Table List 1`, etc. are reserved, and that's why I used `Heading`. However, try to name a NEW STYLE as `TOC 5,smith`; still, you can't. 

(2) The numbers in style names should clarify paragraph levels, at least how developers at Microsoft thought. Level 1 is for chapters, Level 2 is for main sections, Level 3 for sub-sections, and so forth.